# Как узнать имя и расширение файла при скачивании по ссылке?

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

У меня есть ссылки, по ссылкам хочу скачать файлы программно. Знаю, что через `WebClient.Download(url, filename)` можно скачать файл, но таким образом вы сами устанавливаете имя и расширения файла, а мне нужно узнать до скачивания файла имя и расширение.

Answer (score 2):

Интересный вопрос. Думаю, что нужно покопаться в свойствах Headers и QueryString, вашего экземпляра класса WebClient, после скачивания файла:

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://myurl.ru","временыйфайл.doc");

for(int i = 0; i < myWebClient.Headers.Count; i++)
{
    String header = myWebClient.Headers.GetKey(i);
    String[] values = myWebClient.Headers.GetValues(header);
    if(values.Length > 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The values of {0} header are : ", header);
        for(int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++) Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", values[j]);
    }else Console.WriteLine("There is no value associated" + "with the header");
}
```

Comment: Обычно вот тут лежит: Response.Headers.Get("content-disposition") или в даже в Response.Headers.Get("Filename");
Но зависит от сервера, он может и не отдавать название файла.

Comment: Не получается. Вместо "http://myurl.ru" добавляю свою ссылку например "http://zakupki.gov.ru/pgz/documentdownload?documentId=2835573"  и значение myWebClient.Headers.Count = 0, т.е. ни какие значения не показывает. Мне необязательно скачать, мне нужно получить имя файла и расширение.  Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пробую так 
System.Net.HttpWebRequest reqPOST = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://zakupki.gov.ru/pgz/documentdownload?documentId=2835573");
reqPOST.Method = "HEAD";
reqPOST.Timeout = 120000;

System.Net.HttpWebResponse result = (HttpWebResponse)reqPOST.GetResponse();
for (int i = 0; i < result.Headers.Count; i++)
            {
                richEditControl1.Text += result.Headers.Keys[i] + ":" + result.Headers + "\r\n";
            }
Возвращает 404 код ошибки.

Comment: Ну, от этого многомиллионнорублевого сайта я бы не стал ожидать многого, хотя на удивление фидлер показывает, вот что по твоему урлу:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: FRONT-Insert=R2259800618; path=/; expires=Mon, 31-Oct-2011 18:53:17 GMT
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 31 Oct 2011 18:34:52 GMT
Content-Type: application/download
Connection: close
Content-Length: 389120
Content-Disposition: attachment;

Comment: filename="%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%28%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4.%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%8C%29.doc"; filename*=utf-8''%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%28%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4.%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%8C%29.doc
Content-Language:en-US
Expires: Tue, 30 Oct 2012 18:34:52 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Cache-Control: publi

Comment: О прикольно, поломал ребятам разметку. Не буду убирать пусть отладят.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сделать так:

```
    //Отправляем запрос Получаем ответ
```

HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozila/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; 
MyIE2;";

HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

```
  //Получаем интересующий Header файла
```

string Header = myHttpWebResponse.Headers.Get("Content-Disposition");

```
  //Он закодирован, поэтому нужно раскодировать его.
```

Header  = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Header );